# generate route to the namespace itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple different namespaces like this:

```
namespace :some_category do
  resources :orders
  resources :some_foo
  get 'aaa', to: 'aa#aa'
  get 'bbb', to: 'bb#bb'
  # etc
end

namespace :other_namespace do
  resources :foo
  resources :bar
  get 'ccc', to: 'cc#cc'
  get 'ddd', to: 'dd#dd'
  # etc
end

namespace :etc do
end
```

Now, the routes are created correctly. Unfortunately, there aren't any routes generated for the namespaces itself. I would like to also have site.com/some_category and site.com/other_namespace. 
should I just add outside the namespaces

```
get 'some_category', to: 'foo#bar'
get 'other_namespace', to: 'foo#baz'
```

Or is that bad practice?

I would like to make them as some kind of dashboards. Is it possible to generate links to all available subroutes?
I don't like to build a custom dashboard for each namespace. It's not very DRY, because all the dashboards are the same: it is just a list of links, that belongs in that namespace. Is there some code for:

> Get the namespace of which I am the dashboard --> get all routes that are inside that namespace --> generate a link for each of those routes

Comment: Sure, you can add them outside the namespaces. What do you mean, "Is it possible to generate links to all available subroutes?"

Comment: @jvillian I edited my question. I hope it is more clear now?

Comment: inside the namespace you could add `root to: "some_action#some_controller"` which would be essentially the same as adding `get "/", to: "some_action#some_controller"` See [Using root](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root)

Comment: Google around on `Rails.application.routes.routes` and/or `Programmatically List Routes/Paths from inside your Rails App`. That ought to get you started.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky. That was what i was looking for. And I will google some more.